# Deleting an edge in graph for C

Tags: c, igraph

I'm trying to delete a randomly selected edge form a igraph (http://igraph.org/c/) graph called "g".

Igraph's manual for "igraph_delete_edges" function is here: http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Basic.html#igraph_delete_edges But it's still not enough for me to figure it out.

I've got this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <igraph/igraph.h>

int main() {

igraph_t g;
igraph_vector_t v;

igraph_vector_t edges;
igraph_vector_init(&edges,0);

igraph_vector_t indices;
igraph_vector_init(&indices, 0);

igraph_erdos_renyi_game(&g, IGRAPH_ERDOS_RENYI_GNP, 100, .10,IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS); // Create a random graph

igraph_get_edgelist(&g, &edges, 0); // Put the graph's list of indices in "edges"
int r = rand() % igraph_vector_size(&edges); // Get a random edge index

igraph_vector_push_back(&indices, r); // create a vector of size 1 in which to put the random index found above

igraph_delete_edges(&g, igraph_es_vector(&indices)); // Delete that edge
}
```

This doesn't seem to be the way to use igraph_delete_edges (and it sure is very wordy for such a simple operation...) What's the proper way to do use igraph_delete_edges in igraph for C?

Comment: I suspect from the lack of activity over the course of an hour that few people know which package/library the `igraph_vector_t` type comes from. (I certainly don't.) Maybe you should provide a link to it, or show how it is defined, or something?  Read the manual at the link where you obtain the package from before that, though — there might be an example in the documentation.  Note that an MCVE ([MCVE]) is desirable; we can't see how you created the `edges` variable.  Why don't you simply delete an entry from the `edges` before creating the graph?

Comment: Alright, I edited according to your suggestions. Cheers! My gal is to delete a random edge, do some testing on the graph, add another edge, etc.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What is your question, really?

Comment: I tried and made the question a little clearer. cheers!

Comment: `igraph_vector_size(&edges)` will give you *twice* the number of edges because `edges` will have two elements for each edge - one for the source and one for the target. Use `rand() % ((int)igraph_ecount(&g))` instead to select a random edge.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misunderstandings in your code:

- `igraph_get_edgelist()` does not return a list of edge indices. Instead, it returns a list of vertex index pairs, representing edges. Thus the length of the result vector is twice the number of edges.
- If you want to get the number of edges, use `igraph_ecount()`.
- `igraph_es_vector()` takes not one, but two arguments, and requires an existing variable of type `igraph_es_t` into which to construct the edge selector. To create an edge selector without a need for a pre-existing variable, use `igraph_ess_vector()`. This is the "immediate version" of `igraph_es_vector()`.
- If you want to delete a single edge, the simple way is using `igraph_es_1()`.

The code should look something like the following (untested):

```
#include <igraph.h>

int main() {

  igraph_t g;

  igraph_erdos_renyi_game(&g, IGRAPH_ERDOS_RENYI_GNP, 100, .10, IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS); // Create a random graph

  igraph_delete_edges(&g, igraph_es_1(rand() % igraph_ecount(&g)); // Delete random edge

  // do something with g

  igraph_destroy(&g);
}
```