# Deleting edges randomly in igraph C

Tags: c, igraph

> How can I randomly delete edges in Igraph C?

I am using a library called [igraph](http://igraph.org/c/). I am using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows.

I am trying to delete edges randomly from a randomly generated network(network generated using Erdos Renyi Random network generator).

I would appreciate some help in this regard.

The [code is referenced from a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366716/deleting-an-edge-in-graph-for-c). Unfortunately there is no answer to the question on that post either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <igraph/igraph.h>

int main() {

int edgeCount=0;
igraph_t g;
igraph_vector_t v;

igraph_vector_t edges;
igraph_vector_init(&edges,0);

igraph_vector_t indices;
igraph_vector_init(&indices, 0);

igraph_erdos_renyi_game(&g, IGRAPH_ERDOS_RENYI_GNP, 500, .10,IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS); // Create a random graph

igraph_get_edgelist(&g, &edges, 0); // Put the graph's list of indices in "edges"
 int r = rand() % ((int)igraph_ecount(&g)); // Get a random edge index


igraph_vector_push_back(&indices, r); // create a vector of size 1 in which to put the random index found above

 igraph_delete_edges(&g, igraph_es_vector(&indices)); // Delete that edge

 return igraph_ecount(&g);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use a random network generator and delete edges randomly after the network generation. How can I randomly delete edges in Igraph C?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of `igraph`](http://igraph.org/c/doc/) ? You really should!

Comment: And you might ask on some dedicated list, or, after having done some experiments, by a mail to  `igraph@igraph.org`; it is probably  a too specialized software to get an answer on SO

Comment: I posted an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/36366716/695132